# Put header on top of the table

Tags: php

I need to put header on the top of table created by following code. Table has 9 columns. Table is created from Shell script text file.

```
$myfile = file_get_contents('/ftpfiles/monitor-data') or die ("Unable");    
$table = '<table border="2" width="100%" height="500" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 3px solid #0000FF" bordercolorlight="#0000FF">';
$trimmed = trim($myfile);
$filearray = explode("\n", $trimmed);

foreach($filearray as $row) {
    // here separate your row that is a string, into an array
    $cols = explode(" ", $row);
    $table .= '<tr>';
    foreach($cols as $value) {
        $table .= '<td align = "center">'.$value.'</td>';
    }
    $table .= '</tr>';
}

$table .= '</table>';
echo $table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myfile = file_get_contents('/ftpfiles/monitor-data') or die ("Unable");    
$table = '<table border="2" width="100%" height="500" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 3px solid #0000FF" bordercolorlight="#0000FF">';

$table .= '<thead><tr><th>Colname1</th><th>Colname2</th><th>Colname2</th><th>Colname2</th><th>Colname2</th><th>Colname2</th><th>Colname2</th><th>Colname2</th><th>Colname2</th></tr></thead>';

$trimmed = trim($myfile);
$filearray = explode("\n", $trimmed);

foreach($filearray as $row) {
    // here separate your row that is a string, into an array
    $cols = explode(" ", $row);
    $table .= '<tr>';
    foreach($cols as $value) {
        $table .= '<td align = "center">'.$value.'</td>';
    }
    $table .= '</tr>';
}

$table .= '</table>';
echo $table;
```

Comment: Thank You! It worked but it does not align with actual table. I tried align = "Center" but that does not work either.

Comment: Ugh. I wrote this quick and failed to notice I was using tr elements instead of th... my bad. I'll edit the answer. If the alignment is still off, makes sure the number of columns match. Also, using HTML attributes such as "align" is pretty outdated, better to use CSS for such things.

Comment: Ok! Thank You for your help @rob wood!!

Answer (score 0):

use th tag

```
    $myfile = file_get_contents('/ftpfiles/monitor-data') or die ("Unable");    
    $table = '<table border="2" width="100%" height="500" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 3px solid #0000FF" bordercolorlight="#0000FF">';
$table.='<tr>
<th>Head1</th><th>Head2</th>...
</tr>';
    $trimmed = trim($myfile);
    $filearray = explode("\n", $trimmed);

    foreach($filearray as $row) {
        // here separate your row that is a string, into an array
        $cols = explode(" ", $row);
        $table .= '<tr>';
        foreach($cols as $value) {
            $table .= '<td align = "center">'.$value.'</td>';
        }
        $table .= '</tr>';
    }

    $table .= '</table>';
    echo $table;
```